# Trello API - E-mail address of my card returns null

Tags: api, curl, trello

I'm using cURL to send requests to the Trello API.

When I send a `GET` request to get a card's e-mail address (which is used to send comments to a card), the API returns `null`.

I've searched and found that this is usually because the required permission is missing from the token. I have all permissions on the token: `read,write,account`.

The card in question is inside a board on my profile, so I should be able to do this using my own key and token.

If I open the card's normal URL with json (`https://trello.com/c/[short-URL]/card-title.json`), then the e-mail address is there.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Do you still have the problem ? I am trying to get the same information and I have also NULL when I try to get the e-mail.

Comment: @yvan see my answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got an official response from Trello Support, which explains the cause:

> For security reasons, we don't display the card or board email addresses via the API. Having the email-to-board or card email address technically provides write access to the account, even if the token expires, and so we don't expose that information via the API. Although you're a member of that board, there are situations where another person or app could have access to your token, so we don't make that available via the API as a rule.